# Parse push broadcast feature not working suddenly

Tags: parse-platform, push

When I go to send a push broadcast, I get the following message:

No registered devices

You have no registered installations of your app. You can get started with our Quick Start guide.

I have two apps and the other one seems to be working fine.

In fact, it seems that this apps has not been receiving push notifications for a few days now. On November 16 it was still working fine but stopped at some point before November 22.

Any ideas why this has happened? There has been no change on my side.

Comment: Have you used the Parse.initialize code in the app?
Also, could you share details such as for which platform it is and also show us some code?

Comment: It stopped working suddenly without any change on my side. It links to an iOS app. I have a second project which is a clone of the first one and that one works fine. (So, I think it should not be the code ...)

Comment: Sorry, without code i can't help you, especially on ios...

Comment: Well, the problem should not be code related because Parse is simply not seeing any of the installations (over 34K). And I have not edited anything on this app whatsoever.

Comment: Are you sure that you did not mixup the keys or accidentally placed the initialize code in an unreachable place?

Comment: I will check again. However, I sent a successful broadcast on Nov 16 and have definitely not changed anything anywhere since. And how could this affect the previous installations? Is this even possible that it suddenly does not see any of the installations? (I appreciate your attempt to help me!)

Comment: Actually, I tried to test whether the push works on the push quick setup screen ... It finds all the installations there and asks whether I want to send all of them a message ... However, it does not find any installations when I press "Send push".

Comment: can you post some code (with redacted keys) that registers the installation?

Comment: I posted a bug report to Parse and will add it here if it gets resolved.